# How to create dictionary type columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Let me try to ask my questions starting with my intentions.

1. I would like to create two dictionaries (dictionary type inputs are required by the built in functions from Tensorflow, so I must obey it).
2. The keys of the dictionary is defined as

   ```
   _CSV_FEATURE_COLUMNS = ['vgs', 'vbs', 'vds', 'current']
   ```

   and the components that the keys point to are defined under each column of the file I provided

   ```
   train_file = "train_data.csv"
   ```

To those who understand Tensorflow built in functions, I am trying to feed "tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices" a pair of dictionaries so it knows which columns in the .csv file are features and which are labels.

Here is my code trying to do so:

```
 _CSV_FEATURE_COLUMNS = ['vgs', 'vbs', 'vds', 'current']

 features_interim = pd.read_csv(train_file, usecols=['vgs', 'vbs', 'vds', 'current'])
 features_numpy = np.asarray(features_interim, dtype=np.float32)
 features = dict(zip(_CSV_FEATURE_COLUMNS, features_numpy))
```

The train_data.csv looks like [train_data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeRXC.png)

What I am expecting is a dictionary like:
{'vgs': the column with vgs as the first element in the .csv file, 'vbs': the column with vbs as the first element in the .csv file, ...}

But what I am having is way off.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
features_numpy = features_interim.as_matrix().transpose()
```

instead of

```
features_numpy = np.asarray(features_interim, dtype=np.float32)
```